# Why is it necessary for density functions to be absolutely continuous with respect to a measure in order for the cross entropy to be defined?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, absolute-continuity

In the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) describing cross entropy, the following expression is written down to denote the cross entropy $H$ between two densities $p(x)$ and $q(x)$:

$H(p,q) = - \int_\mathcal{X}p(x)\log q(x)dr(x)$

The page mentions that "$p$ and $q$ must be absolutely continuous with respect to some measure $r$ (usually $r$ is a Lebesgue measure on a Borel $\sigma$-algebra)".

The definition of absolute continuity is this: Let $I$ be an interval on the real line; let $(x_k, y_k)$ be a finite sequence of pairwise disjoint sub-intervals of $I$ where $x_k < y_k \in I$;  a function $f$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $I$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that    we have $\sum_k (y_k - x_k) < \delta \implies \sum_k|f(y_k) - f(x_k)|<\epsilon$

I have some intuition for what absolute continuity with respect to $I$ might mean - if I want the output to change by a tiny amount $\epsilon$ from $f(x_k)$ to $f(y_k)$, an absolutely continuous function on $I$ guarantees that I only need to push $x_k$ by a tiny amount that is upper bounded by $\delta$. But why is this an important assumption to make in order for the cross entropy to be defined? I just don't see the link at all, and I am looking for some intuition.

Comment: This is a non-issue - if $P$ and $Q$ are probability measures, they are always absolutely continuous with respect to the reference measure $P+Q$. I think that they explicitly assume this to make sure that writing densities is meaningful (and so they avoid writing the proper definition which involves derivatives between measures [R-N derivatives] which might be unnecessary complication for an introduction). That said, there is an actual problem here, which is that if $P$ is not absolutely continous with respect to $Q$, then the cross entropy trivialises to $+\infty$.

Comment: Your linked Wikipedia page starts "two probability distributions $p$ and $q$" not "two probability densities $p$ and $q$".  It is absolute continuity of these distributions which then allows discussion of their density functions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Absolute continuity" has two different definitions depending on the context. (They are related, which is why they share the same name, but the relation is not immediately obvious.)

---

The definition you cited ($\sum_k (y_k - x_k) < \delta \implies \sum_k |f(y_k) - f(x_k)| < \epsilon$) is for [absolute continuity of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_functions). However, what your statement is really about is [absolute continuity of measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures). Specifically, when they say "$p$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $r$", they are talking about the probability measures whose densities are $p$ and $r$, and not about the actual density functions $p$ and $r$.

In fact, for a probability measure to even *have* a density function with respect to a reference measure is one equivalent definition of absolutely continuity with respect to that reference measure. (For instance, in undergrad probability you deal with "continuous random variables" that have a density function on $\mathbb{R}$; we would say these distributions are *absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure*.) If a probability measure $P$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to a reference measure $R$, then it does not even have a density function $p$ such that $P(A) = \int_A p(x) \, dR(x)$.

So, regarding the discussion about cross-entropy, it is basically saying that "in order to even write down the integral $\int p(x) \log q(x) \, dr(x)$, we need to know whether the probability measures $P$ and $Q$ have densities with respect to a reference measure $R$." If you are even able to write down this integral, you've already assumed the necessary absolute continuity condition.

---

Finally, the way the [two separate notions of absolute continuity are related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Relation_between_the_two_notions_of_absolute_continuity) is through the CDF (**not** the density function). Specifically, the measure $P$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t the Lebesgue measure if and only if the function $F(x) = P((-\infty, x])$ is absolutely continuous [as a function] on $\mathbb{R}$.